# Scaffold in Rails 2.2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Ruby on Rails apparently changed the syntax for creating scaffold. I'm trying an example that says to use:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold tale tale
ruby script/generate scaffold genre genre
```

The database tables are named "genres" and "tales". When I don't repeat, it works ok:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold tale
ruby script/generate scaffold genre
```

However, the localhost/genre does not work as described in the book. I can access the page using localhost/genres, but when I select "create" the page only shows:

New genre

(Create button)

Back

Am I missing something that is required to show the input field? 
"show create table genres" shows the table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `genre_name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Comment: Is there any real reason to learn (as I'm guessing from the question, you are learning, not trying to fix some old app) Rails 2.2 in 2011? It's more than two years old.

Comment: Rails 2.2 was installed from repository. You're right, this is a bit old. The book is even older, I noticed a screenshot in the book says 1.8.6 is the current version! Has RoR 3 mostly replaced RoR 2, or is it more like Python-3? The RoR site has a link to both 3.x and 2.x versions.

Comment: Rubygems repository contains each and every Rails version, down to 0.8.0 from 2004; that does not mean you actually should use it. Even if you (for some reason) prefer to stick with Rails 2.x, you should use 2.3.12: it's the most recent 2.x release, a month old. I should say, through, that Rails 3.x is definitely and doubtlessly the future: 3.0 is pretty stable, 3.1 is maturing, and given that you are learning, there's really no reason you should use 2.x.

Comment: I'm with @whitequark, use the 3.0.x or 3.1.x versions. And make sure you learn/hone how to write good tests...it is a good thing to do anyway, and will also allow you to switch to future "disruptive/wildly changed" Rails versions more easily than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the scaffold to generate the input fields on the form, you should pass them in the command itself.

```
ruby script/generate scaffold genre genre_name:string description:text
```

that will generate the same db table you show and with the proper input fields on the views.